# Inject a property programatically in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I would like to know how to inject a property an object of a component.

Below is the App Container component code

```
<FormItem element={<FormItemText />} />
```

Below are the 2 component.

```
FormItem extends Component {

  saysomething(){
    console.log("Saying something")
  }

  render(){
    return (
      {this.props.element}
    )
  }

}
```

and

```
FormItemText extends Component {

  render(){
    return (
      <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => this.props.saysomething(text)}
    )
  }

}
```

How do I pass along the FormItem.saysomething as a property to FormItemText component.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `direct manipulation` to inject a property programatically.

1. First add a `ref` attribute to your `FormItemText` component.
2. Create a function to call `setNativeProps` on your `TextInput.onChangeText`.
3. Done!

Note that `direct manipulation` is computationally intensive - React needs to re-render the component hierarchy each time the opacity changes, even though other properties of the view and its children haven't changed. Usually this overhead isn't a concern but when performing continuous animations and responding to gestures, judiciously optimizing your components can improve your animations' fidelity.

For more information and examples, read React Native Documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html).

Answer (score 0):

We do something similar to what you're asking.

We have a Form component that accepts a number of FormInputs as children:

```
<Form>
  <FormInput />
  <FormInput />
</Form>
```

The Form needs to give some functions and properties to the FormInput.  For example, the FormInput may need to scroll the parent Form when it is focused.

We do this using a React context
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html

In your example, it would end up looking something like this:

```
<FormItem>
    <FormItemText />
</FormItem>

FormItem extends Component {
  getChildContext() {
    return { saysomething: this.saysomething };
  }

  saysomething(){
    console.log("Saying something")
  }

  render(){
    return (
      {this.props.children}
    )
  }
}
FormItem.childContextTypes = {
  saysomething: PropTypes.func,
};

FormItemText extends Component {    
  render(){
    return (
      <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => this.context.saysomething(text)}
    )
  }
}
FormItemText.contextTypes = {
  saysomething: PropTypes.func,
};
```